# Magento2 product download view video issues

Tags: file, magento2, video-processing, magento2.2

I create a product downloadable with file video/book.

The current, when I added a sample file and go to frontend -> click sample link. I can view MP3, Mp4 video file.
However, if I use file: pub file, wmv, flv, wav, avi
It will automatic download (not opening for view)

Expect: I would like to view file with format: pub file, wmv, flv, wav, avi and not download. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide one of your website addresses?

Comment: Now I see what you mean,but support and compatibility of different browsers for different video formats is a very bad thing,I suggest you save your video to a third-party platform (eg youtube),then you just need to put the appropriate url in the html code.

Comment: I think so, but I am curious why cms page can use it.

Comment: Can you provide your cms_page template? I want to try it on my local